# Expire module configured to 0, but swf is allways loading from cache

Tags: apache-2.2, lighttpd, cache

I am trying to load an swf flash file from my **lighttpd** web server.

> expire.url "/static/swf" => 
>   "modification plus 0 seconds"

However, when I reload from the web browser, chrome seems to load the file from cache.
Same with firefox. In this one with firebug I see the files are loading from cache although the header is showing a "**Cache-Control**" of "**max-age=0**"

Could you tell me why chrome or firefox use cache instead of loading the files when I am telling that I do not want to cache these type of files.

Thank you.

Comment: I think what may be missing is the "must-revalidate" Cache-Control header, but I don't know how to make lighttpd issue that header in addition to max-age.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, that 0 means infinite, as usual.

Comment: Expires give me the same time as I am making the request. If 0 means infinite, could you tell me how could I change this value in order to get the results I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ ".(swf)$" {
etag.use-inode = "disable"
etag.use-mtime = "disable"
etag.use-size = "disable"
static-file.etags = "disable"
}
```

I have tried this, but **304 Not Modified** is responded.

```
curl -I http://static.lucas.net/static/swf/titles.swf
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash
Accept-Ranges: bytes
**Last-Modified**: Fri, 01 Apr 2011 09:34:05 GMT
```

Last-Modified is the problem.

Comment: Ok. The problem was that I had not enable the mod_setenv. The solution is make it available.